# Warning: Prop `className` did not match and window is not defined in Next 13 App Router

Tags: javascript, next.js, window, warnings

I have one headache with solving an error in Next.js 13 App Router.

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. 
Server: "styled__HeadLink-sc-6589f63-0 fIOFTm" 
Client: "styled__HeadLink-sc-b76127ed-0 jzAIeh"
```

I've certainly done a lot of Googling for information on how to solve this problem. The most unpleasant thing about errors is that they can be hard to find.

- So, to resolve this issue, I followed the recommendations I found on the internet.

My .babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": [["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }]]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }]],
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }]]
}
```

next.config.js

```
reactStrictMode: false,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
```

I used window checks in the code.

```
export const isClient = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

I also tried using next/dynamic.

```
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(VeryTroubleBlock), { ssr: false });
```

It seems like I found the problem where it occurs, specifically, only during the initial rendering of Swiper.

```
const isTablet = useAdaptiveSize(Breakpoints.tablet);
const isMobile = useAdaptiveSize(Breakpoints.mobile);

return (
<div className="here_is_trouble">
        {isTablet ? (
          <Swiper
            modules={[Pagination, A11y]}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            slidesPerView={isMobile ? 1 : 2}
            spaceBetween={24}
          >
            {managers.map((manager: TroubleBlockProps, index: number) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={`${index}`}>
                <ManagerItems {...manager} />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        ) : (
          <>
            {managers.map((manager) => (
              <ManagerItems key={manager.name} {...manager} />
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
)
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(VeryTroubleBlock), { ssr: false });
```

My custom hook

```
import { isClient } from '@/utils/client-check';
import { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useWindowSize } from 'usehooks-ts';

export function useAdaptiveSize(size: number): boolean {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const [isTablet, setIsTablet] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isClient()) setIsTablet(width < size);
  }, [width]);

  return isTablet;
}
```

What's interesting is that my custom hook helped me solve the problem on one page of my application, but on the second page with this Swiper, there is an issue.

There is, of course, a solution to get rid of the "Warning: Prop **`className`** did not match" error. You need to replace the execution of the custom hook with **`innerWidth < Breakpoints.tablet`**. This eliminates the console error, but it appears on the server, indicating that **`window is not defined`**.

I'm open to any criticism and willing to accept help in solving this problem.

Have a great day, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
The issue stemmed from the fact that my global styles were written in CSS, while the remaining styles were implemented using styled-components.

Answer:
To address this issue, I opted to transition to using Styled-components for all styling needs. This unified the styling approach and ensured consistency in styling both during server-side and client-side rendering. Additionally, I removed the use of React.Fragment `<></>` in the `StyleSheetManager` during the `return styles` phase.

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components';

export default function StyledComponentsRegistry({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // Only create stylesheet once with lazy initial state
  // x-ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state
  const [styledComponentsStyleSheet] = useState(() => new ServerStyleSheet());

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const styles = styledComponentsStyleSheet.getStyleElement();
    styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance.clearTag();
    return styles;
  });

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') return <>{children}</>;

  return <StyleSheetManager sheet={styledComponentsStyleSheet.instance}>{children}</StyleSheetManager>;
}
```